# how to add max_input_var php 5.3.3?

Tags: php, .htaccess, plesk

I got a plesk server running plesk 12 and php 5.3.3,
i got a client who is running Prestashop,
I need to add something to the language but before I can do that I need to add `max_input_var` to `6000` it is now `1000`
I've search everything on google but i can't find an solution for it.
there is no `php.ini` file? in the root or other directory's.
i've tried to add things like (`max_input_var` etc.) in the `.htaccess` file but it didn't work,
i've tried to add it on my server `/etc/php.ini` & `/var/www/vhost/domain/etc/php/ini`
but is still stays on `1000`
do i need to update php?
I am to afraid to update cause of the problems it may give.

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` to see the loaded `*.ini` files, make sure it's set in the main `php.ini` and not reset to 1000 somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're running PHP in FCGI (which you probably are) then you can easily update PHP without any trouble. PHP 5.3 is EOL and you should make your server more secure by upgrading to at least 5.4. Check out [Atomicorp Panda](https://atomicorp.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7279) for more information.

Second, Plesk tends to segment each client into its own area. You can't just edit their php.ini or httpd.conf because Plesk generates those. What you'll need to do is create a `vhost.conf` file in their `conf` directory. You can then do something like this (change the path to their directory)

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com>
      php_admin_flag engine on 
      php_admin_value max_input_var 6000
</Directory>
```

Comment: After upgrading to php 5.6 and putting max_input_vars = 6000 in plesk is finaly worked !

thanks mate !